# Statically linking DPDK creates mempool failure

Tags: dpdk

I am using DPDK 21.11.2 as packaged on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

I have a very simple program that initialize the EAL and then create a small 32b mempool.

Everything works perfectly when dynamically linking with DPDK (`pkg-config --libs`).

However, when statically linking DPDK (`pkg-config --libs --static`), I observe weird runtime behaviors. Everything build and link without problem though.

The initialization of the EAL goes well, I can see that DPDK detect static linking in the logs, but creating any kind of mempool will return NULL and rte_errno is set to `2` (file not found).

I am confused as to what kind of magic DPDK is trying to do with static/dynamic linkage detection. As far as I can tell, all DPDK symbols that I use are defined in my statically linked binary.

Comment: It looks like you've done this properly, so, a solution might involve checking for additional dependencies that are not automatically included by pkg-config. It's possible that some shared resources or modules used by DPDK for mempool functionality are not being linked correctly in the static build.